# Simplest device for mini operating system

Tags: lcd, os, silkscreen

I have been developing an operating system off of [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZRlrJjuZL8s) and I want to begin building a device to support this os. All it really does is print to the screen. I want to build a small device with an lcd color screen that can boot this os (from something like an sd card) and is as simple as possible.

What parts would I need to build a small and portable device that can print the output onto a small lcd screen?

Comment: Please state your requirements in your question rather than linking to a video.  Generally today though, it comes down to memory footprint and if you need hardware-enforced memory protection and/or virtual addressing, as those are (approximately) the dividing line between what you can do on a flash microcontroller, and more complicated versions (not infrequently of the same processor architecture) with external memory interfaces and memory management units.

Comment: Sorry. I will edit it. I'm just having a hard time phrasing my question.

Comment: You've still failed to specify what your operating system requires in the way of hardware support to be able to run.  Also, what sort of display - text?  graphics?  What buffer dimensions?  These are the kinds of questions which always matter, and extremely so on very small systems.

Comment: FYI, it looks like the those with less patience have started downvoting and close voting your question.

Comment: ALright I will edit it again. This time I will be more specific

Answer (score 1):

Parts selection is actually quite a lot of work. Especially to vague requirements. Even just the question of an LCD screen is complicated (what size? pixel addressable? integrated controller? e.g. [Efficient display of simple text/graphics on color LCD by ARM](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/13935/efficient-display-of-simple-text-graphics-on-color-lcd-by-arm?rq=1) )

Then there's the question of what architecture(s) your operating system should run on, what features it should have, etc.

The video appears to refer to some sort of generic PC operating system, designed to boot on the "bare metal" of a PC. For that you will be best off with an old or cheap laptop to start with.

If you want to build your own OS, ARM is probably a good platform to start with; you might be able to find a dev board with a built in LCD, that would save you a lot of hardware work.